# Ajax image upload causes unexpected output in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I have worked around to make an ajax request for uploading a picture and I have used the below piece of code.

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upl"/>
</form>

<script> // all other jquery dependencies are added for ajax file upload 
$(function(){

      $('#upload').fileupload({
      add: function (e, data) {
           var jqXHR = data.submit();    
        },
      success:function(result){
                alert(result);
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

My `upload.php`

```
<?php if(isset($_FILES['upl'])){
      $file = 'some random name'; // generated using rand functions in php
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'],$file ))
        echo 'success';
      }
?>
```

On success I was expecting jQuery to alert `success` and it works perfectly fine in chrome and other browsers but when it comes to IE 7 it alerts  `[object Object]` as output but I expect it to be `success`

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: it works if i use result.text() in IE but using this does not seem to work in chrome :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In upload.php, instead of echoing the output using

```
echo 'success';
```

you could return the JSON representation of the object using the function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

This way you can parse the json with javascript and use the parsed string in your alert.
This method is cleaner than the one you are using and possibly compatible with older versions of IE (you might also need to use the [JSON.stringify](http://json.org/js.html) function to convert the parsed JSON into a string).

Answer (score 0):

may be JSON object is not created in IE8 and IE7

add JSON.js file in your page